# Getting vertex of modified Stanford Bunny

Tags: plotting

I did some changes on the vertex of `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}]` and I plotted it again using [`ListSurfacePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSurfacePlot3D.html) function.
Now, I would like to get the vertex back from the plotted new bunny. Any help please?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? It's helpful to know exactly what you did, exactly what you're trying to do, and exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Per the documentation of [`ListSurfacePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSurfacePlot3D.html):

[image]
So I think it's safe to just extract the coordinates manually:

```
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];
plot = ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 35];

pts = plot[[1, 1]];

Graphics3D[Point[pts], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]